# Validations in form_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

In my online shop I want to have validation before adding a product to the cart

my order_item form is in the product show

I want to force the user to select  a size, and display an **error message** if no size chosen ?

Size is a nested attributes of products

How I am supposed to write it?

```
<%= form_tag clients_order_items_path, input_html: {id: "orderform"} do %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :product_id, @product.id %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :user_id, @token %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :quantity, 1 %>            
    <%= select_tag :size_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@product.sizes.where('quantity >=1'), :id, :size_name), prompt: "Your Size", class: 'form-control custom-select'%>  
<%= submit_tag "Add to cart", class: "btn-main", id: "add_to_cart" %>
```

here is the OrderItemsController with the create method:

```
 def create
    @item = current_cart
    @size = Size.find(params[:size_id])

    if @size.quantity >= params[:quantity].to_i

      current_cart.add_item(
        product_id: params[:product_id],
        quantity: params[:quantity],
        size_id: params[:size_id],
      )

      redirect_to clients_cart_path
    else
      redirect_to clients_product_path(Product.find(params[:product_id]))

    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To force user to select one size:

```
<%= select_tag :size_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@product.sizes.where('quantity >=1'), :id, :size_name), {include_blank: 'Your Size'}, required: true, class: 'form-control custom-select'%>
```

This will make the `select` required, and the browser custom message will appears if size not selected.

If you want to customize the message, and shows **before** the request are made, consider use JS, i recommends https://jqueryvalidation.org/

*OBS*: Its a good pratice, don't perform databases queries on your view, consider to make `@product.sizes.where('quantity >=1')` in your controller like:

```
# Inside your controller
def show
    ...
    @product_size_options = @product.sizes.where('quantity >=1')
    ...
end
```

and your  `select_tag`:

```
<%= select_tag :size_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@product_size_options, :id, :size_name), {include_blank: 'Your Size'}, required: true, class: 'form-control custom-select'%>
```